# Multiple pods writes to same logging file

Tags: kubernetes

Consider there is one `rollout` in K8s setting and it creates 2 `replicaSet`s, each replicaSet has a single `pod`. Each pod include the same application that has a `volume` to directory with same value (i.e. /dir/logs/)

```
Rollout
  |_____ReplicaSet1
            |_______Pod1
                |________Volume (/logs/ mount to /dir/logs/)
  |_____ReplicaSet2
            |_______Pod2
                |________Volume (/logs/ mount to /dir/logs/)
```

If application in `Pod1` will output log to file

```
 /logs/application.log
```

And application in `Pod2` has the same definition

```
 /logs/application.log
```

is it going to be an `locking` issue, so that application in `pod1` can write data in /logs/application.log that application in `pod2` can't access the file because it is being written by `pod1`? How to configure `K8s` so that multiple pods won't facing such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the pod name as an environment variable and then use this as part of your log path:

```
...
          env:
            - name: PODNAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - |
              exec myapplication --logfile /logs/$PODNAME.log
...
```